# Check if URL exists (method doesn't work with "http://" string)

Tags: java, network-programming

In Java I'm trying to verify that a URL exists. I do this by creating a URL object, then calling URL.openConnection, then calling URLConnection.connect(), then calling URL.openStream(). None of these throw an exception with this URL: "http://", which makes no sense.

I need the method to be protocol independent.

Comment: `http:\\` is an invalid protocol specification. `http://` would be the correct way to reference it. (Note the **forward** slashes as opposed to the **backslashes** you used.)

Comment: Did you mean: `http://` (forward slashes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the response code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://");
HttpURLConnection   conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
conn.disconnect();
```

If it doesn't throw an exception, the URL exists. This one threw

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
```

for me.

Comment: Great, thank you.  It's not protocol independent but I think i'm only going to end up using http anyway.

Comment: @Anthony I should have added that you need to check the response code. If it is 200 the resource exists.

Comment: I guess I could just add a check for url.getHost == null, but this is still kind of weird

Comment: actually it would be url.getHost() == null || url.getHost().length == 0

Comment: @Anthony the default host is 'localhost', so that indicates you have an HTTP server running at localhost:80. So the code is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check if the url is valid and then perform the request you could user commons validator ( http://commons.apache.org/validator/ ) so you can execute openConnection() just in case the url is really valid.

Documentation and sample here: http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a library?  Just java.